# flaskrestplus возвращает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask

У меня есть метод `PUT`, который реализован с помощью `flask-restplus` и работает с разбором аргументов:

```
@api.expect(upload_index, validate=True)
def put(self):
    args = arguments.upload_index.parse_args(strict=True)
```

`upload_index` выглядит так:

```
upload_index = reqparse.RequestParser()
upload_index.add_argument('async', default=False, type=inputs.boolean, help="Is need async request")
upload_index.add_argument('limit', default=None, type=int, help="Maximum number of documents to upload")
```

При этом, когда я передаю в хэдерах: `{"Content-Type": "application/json"}`, получаю:

```
'The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.'
```

Почему реализована такая логика? Где в стандарте она описана?